# create Two dimensional arraylist using split function and bind into gridview in asp.net c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have two string containing list of ids
and respective values.

I want to add them in gridview like we have table with id and proper value.

I have already try this for only "id"
below code is for only "id"

```
    string id = "1,2,3,4,5";
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
    list.AddRange(id.Split(new char[] { ',' }));
    GridView1.DataSource = list;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

we have one column and five rows in gridview on execution of this code.

but i need two columns having id and values.
how can we do this ?

```
    string id = "1,2,3,4,5";
    string value = "abc,pqr,xyz,mno,qwe";
    ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
    list.AddRange(id.Split(new char[] { ',' }));
    list.AddRange(value.Split(new char[] { ',' }));
    GridView1.DataSource = list;
    GridView1.DataBind();
```

this give me single column having 10 rows instead of this i want two columns each i have respective id and values.

Comment: Maybe what you want is a `Dictionary`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try :

```
string id = "1,2,3,4,5";
string value = "abc,pqr,xyz,mno,qwe";

var ids = id.Split(new char[] { ',' });
var values = value.Split(new char[] { ',' });

ArrayList list = new ArrayList();
for (int i = 0; i < ids.Length; i++)
    list.Add(new [] {ids[i], values[i]});
GridView1.DataSource = list;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Hope this will help

Comment: It gives "IndexOutOfRangeException"

-->  list.Add(new [] {ids[i], values[i]});

Comment: @AadiPatel works here. Are you testing with the values above ? I assume ids and values are the same length (they must be)

Comment: I have just have checked my string values.
Now Its not showing any error to me. But it gives some un-expected results in gridview

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this:

```
string id = "1,2,3,4,5";
string value = "abc,pqr,xyz,mno,qwe";
var ids = id.Split(new char[] { ',' });
var values = value.Split(new char[] { ',' });

Dictionary<string, string> listDict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
for (int i = 0; i < ids.Length; i++)
{
    listDict.Add(ids[i], values[i]);
}

gridView1.DataSource = listDict;
gridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: Its true that i don't need dictionary.. but your code works nicely.
Thanks